# Ho to enable www in domain name in azure?

Tags: azure, web, dns

I am hosting my project in azure in my own domain but it only can have access to it with this url domain.com but with www.domain.com cannot have access to it.

Is there anywhere in azure panel to enable www?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to map a CNAME record for `www.yourdomain.com` to `yourapp.azurewebsites.net` from with your domain registrar's DNS panel.

For more information, see the custom domain documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/#create-the-dns-records